# How to make Spring Cloud Consul register with external IP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, consul

How to make Spring Cloud Consul register with external IP?

I run spring boot applications with spring cloud consul in docker.
The application is running inside a docker network on a docker swarm.

This means that if spring consul registers with the hostname or the IP address it will get an hostname or ip address that is internal to the docker swarm. My consul server is outside the docker swarm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.ipAddress` externally and set the property `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.preferIpAddress=true`.

Alternatively, you can [control which network interfaces](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/blob/master/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-commons.adoc#ignore-network-interfaces) to derive an ip address from.

In Brixton you can ignore interfaces:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - docker0
        - veth.*
```

In Camden (currently RC1) you can also whitelist networks:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      preferredNetworks:
        - 192.168
        - 10.0
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no interface on the host machine that has the external IP.
Also, there is no way of knowing which machine docker swarm is going to run the docker image on. 
I will try to run code to detect the external IP before spring boot starts though and set the parameter you specified.

It is sad though that consul cannot just take the external ip of the person that registers or that spring boot does not have a mechanism for resolving external ip.

Comment: I never understand when folks say it's sad. Spring Cloud is trying to guess and not just for docker, otherwise operator has to tell it. PRs welcome if you have an idea besides sadness.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant to say I would have liked that feature. I understand this is not a simple task and that there are many things to consider in such a feature. I would definitely send a PR if I had the time. 
Also I want to state I am very grateful for Spring Cloud  Consul.

Comment: NP. I apologize if I sounded frustrated. Thanks for the feedback, you could log an issue if you don't have time for a PR

Comment: I just used the properties `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.ipAddress=42.42.42.42` and `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.preferIpAddress=false` in bootstrap.properties and spring consul still registers with hotsname: `Registering service with consul: NewService{id='config-core-8082', name='config-core', tags=[], address='nlacombe-ai', port=8082, check=Check{script='null', interval=10s, ttl=null, http=http://nlacombe-ai:8082/health, tcp=null, timeout=null}} @org.springframework.cloud.consul.discovery.ConsulLifecycle`

Comment: Since you set IP address use prefer IP address true

Comment: It works now :) Thank you.
You should updated to `spring.cloud.consul.discovery.preferIpAddress=true` in your answer though since I specified IP in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Run the container with -p 12345:12345 to publish the port so that you can access the container from your host machine through the specified port

Comment: This is what I do. My problem is that the application does not register with the good IP. It registers with a private IP or a virtual hostname. Which makes it unreachable from the consul server and from any computer outside the docker swarm network.

Comment: After publishing the open ports you need to use your host ip not the docker one

Comment: Spring Cloud Consul is the application component that is auto-detecting the IP/Host and not me doing it manually. My goal is to make spring cloud consul register with the host IP. How do you suggest I do so?